# Is it possible to assign the contents of ... to another variable?

Tags: r, function, arguments

I am writing a function that needs to work whether it is given the arguments as in my_fun(arg1, arg2, arg3,..., argn) or my_fun(arg1, list(arg2, arg3,..., argn)) Is that possible?

I tried the following (where do_stuff is a function that works with a list as the second argument) but the assignment `input <- ...` does not work. Can you find an alternative?

```
my_fun <- function(arg1,...) {
  if(class(..1)!="list") {  
    input <- list(...)
  } else {
    input <- ...
  }
  return(do_stuff(arg1, input))
}
```

Comment: Why not explicitly state the arguments? Why should they use `...`?!

Comment: `...` allows to call named objets in function. I would use a named list here to check what names are provided. Or you can use `missing` to check what arguments are in the function call.

Comment: Because I want it to work with both the input given as a list or as separate arguments, and for any number of arguments. I edit to clarify that

Comment: would `...` have more than 1 length always ?

Comment: @RonakShah No, it can have any length, including 1. Anyway, I have found a silly way to make it work. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

Just use `input <- (...)` instead of `input <- ...` and for some reason it works!